# Access DataTemplate element via xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I want to access `txtLang`(textblock existing in the template) TextBlock from my MainWindow xaml via CommandParameter.

How can I do that? Here's the code:

Main Window:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TreeViewDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding PLanguageCollection}"/>
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TreeView,Path="SelectedItem...//What is the path?
```

Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Height="25" Width="25" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
            <TextBlock Name="txtLang"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Language}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

**EDIT:**

MainWindow:

```
   <Button Content="Create Project">

              <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="txtDesc"/>
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="txtName"/>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="ListBox"/>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem.Language" ElementName="TreeView"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
```

Converter:

```
   public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values)
        {
            Tuple<string, string> tuple = new Tuple<string, string>(
                (string)values[0], (string)values[1]);
            return (object)tuple;
        }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

           if(values[3] is string)
        {
            Service1 service1 = new Service1();
            service1.CreateProject2((string) values[0], (string) values[1], (string) values[2], (string) values[3]);
        } 
        return null;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The thrown exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.String'.
```

I understand this happens because the DependencyProperty at the begining is "Unset" because it's being loaded at runtime by the dataTemplate.
But how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{Binding SelectedItem.Language}`, or possibly `{Binding SelectedItem.DataContext.Language}` if your `SelectedItem` returns a `TreeViewItem` instead of your data object

The objects inside a DataTemplate doesn't actually exist until the template is used, so you can't reference like you would other objects. In addition, if the template is used multiple times, you'll have multiple TextBlocks named "txtLang", so your code wouldn't know which object to refer to.

I always think of DataTemplates as cookie cutters. You can't reference the cookie until you use the cookie cutter to make at least one cookie :)

Comment: I edited my post with detailed information I get due to this change in my code. Hope you can help me!

Comment: @idish Based on the code you posted, I suspect the problem is happening in your Converter somewhere since bindings usually only give warnings, not exceptions. I'd put a break point there and test each value to see what it is, and add appropriate handling there. More than likely one of the values can't be cast as a string.

Comment: The last Binding(the 4th) is the one who creates the exception. It is because I see in the debug mode that the Dependency Property is Unset and that's why it can't cast it into a string.

Comment: @idish You should be able to check if it's `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` then, and if so use a blank string :)

Comment: Rachel, I'm really sorry about the very late response, I've been very busy.. I don't really understand where should I place the checking if the DependencyProperty, here's what I found: http://siderite.blogspot.com/2010/02/checking-if-wpf-property-is-set-or-not.html

Comment: @idish You would perform the check in your Converter. You'll need to check if `values[3]` is `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, and if so use `string.Empty` instead of `(string)values[3]`, because `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` cannot be cast as a string. Or you could try using `(values[3] as string)`, which should return `null` if the value can't be cast as a string.

Comment: Alright, it really works now, (I mean there's no exception being thrown). Although I'm facing another problem now: I want the operation to be submitted once I click on the button, but if I debug my project, I see that the "Convert" is being called everytime anything happens, I really don't understand why.. Can you please explain me why it happens and if there's any solution for that? I want the Convert function to be called only when the button is clicked. I RE-Edited the "Converter" in my post^^. I'd really like to thank you for your help! Thank you very much.

Comment: I think it happens because there is no UpdateSourceTrigger, is that right? I want the convert method to be called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Ehm, I will accept your answer since you helped me much more than the help I've requested in the begining, anyways, I'll be very glad if you could help me with my last problem.. I really can't figure how to do that. Anyways, thank you so much!

Comment: @idish The converter will run anytime the property gets evaluated, or depending on how your Command is setup, it might even get re-evaluated anytime any property changes. If you only want it to run when the button is clicked, you can probably set the {Binding ...} `Mode` property to `Explicit`, and manually run it when the button is clicked. But if that doesn't work, your best bet would probably be to post a new SO question containing the sample code to reproduce your problem :)

Comment: Hmm, I posted SO question, someone answered me but it doesn't seem to me like the right answer, can you please try to help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478931/updatesourcetrigger-button-click-converter#comment20173671_14478931

Comment: @idish That looks like it should work fine. `Button.Click` runs before `Button.Command`, so you can use the `Click` event to set the `Button.CommandParameter` from the Code Behind, using your Converter to parse the value.