# UpdateSourceTrigger button click Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

With the following code, the Convert method is being called when one of the DependencyProperties are being updated/changed.

I want the converter to be called only when the button is clicked.
How can I do that?

Here's the code:

```
 <Button Content="Create Project">

                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit"  Mode="TwoWay">
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="txtDesc"/>
                        <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="txtName"/>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="ListBox"/>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem.Language" ElementName="TreeView"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>

            </Button>
```

Comment: May be will be easier write Click handler for this button?

Comment: xaml: <Button Content="Create Project" Click="OnClick">  cs:    IMultiValueConverter multiValueConverter = new MyConverter();
            object[] values =new object[4];
            values[1] =  txtDesxr.Text;
            ...
            object convResult=multiValueConverter.Convert(values,...);

Comment: @Frank59 You should post that as an answer, along with the code sample. I think it should work fine, since `Button.Click` runs before `Button.Command`, so you should be able to use it to set the `Button.CommandParameter`

Comment: @Frank59 Can you please post it as an answer for my specific code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think will correct something like this code:

**xaml**

```
 <Button Content="Create Project" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

**cs**

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string param1 = txtDesc.Text;
        string param2 = txtName.Text;
        object param3 = ListBox.SelectedItem;
        object param4 = TreeView.SelectedItem;

        object convertResult = MyConverterUtils.Convert(param1, param2, param3, param4);
        (sender as Button).CommandParameter = convertResult;
        //or you can execute some method here instead of set CommandParameter
    }


    public class MyConverterUtils 
    {
         //convert method
         //replace Object on your specific types 
         public static Object Convert(string param1, string param2,Object  param3,Object param4)
         {
             Object convertResult=null;

             //convert logic for params and set convertResult
             //for example convertResult = (param1 + param2).Trim();

             return convertResult;
         } 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late comment.

Answer (score -1):

With [MVVM](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=es&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=wpf%20mvvm%20code%20project) it can be very easy:

1. Declare a `ICommand` in your MVVM using [RelayCommand](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=es&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=wpf%20RelayCommand).
2. Bind the Button's `Command` property to the declared command.
3. Do your logic in the Command's Execute method.
4. Update the required properties.

**ViewModel**

```
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand UpdateSomething { get; private set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            UpdateSomething = new RelayCommand(MyCommandExecute, true);
        }

        private void MyCommandExecute(object parameter)
        {
            // Your logic here, for example using your converter if
            // you really need it.

            // At the end, update the properties you need
            // For example adding a item to an ObservableCollection.
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
    <Button Content="Create Project" Command="{Binding UpdateSomething}"/>
```